# Stable manifold theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

The stable manifold theorem says that there exists a stable manifold and an unstable manifold with the dimension corresponding to the dimension of its eigenspace of its linearized operator. I have the following question

---

1. Is such decomposition unique, i.e. Can we find other stable manifold?
2. What about the behavior of the point not on these two manifold? By Hartman Gorbman, we know if a point is on stable manifold , then at some time t<0, it will go out a neighborhood of the equilibrium point

Comment: The stable Manifold is Unique, as is the unstable manifold.  For points not on the manifolds, Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Col_(meteorology)

Comment: If it is unique why we can have homoclinic orbit in 2d

Comment: I am certainly no expert, but the "stable set about p" is uniquely defined to be the points that converge to p.  When I was in grad school back in the 90's, we made computer programs to compute approximations to stable manifolds.  If I recall correctly, there were conditions on the differential equation which would guaranteed the existence of manifolds that covered the stable set.  I don't remember those conditions. It's not too hard to imagine dynamic systems in $ R^2$ whose stable set is the union of several one dimensional manifolds.